# asp.net config settings for web.config with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-config

I have a simple  aspx page that is being used along with javascripts that are loaded from a folder inside the project , there is no issue really as I am able to make the javascript work on aspx page but I wanted to know why the javascript works correctly when I use the following setting in web.config

```
    `<handlers>
    <remove name="WebDAV"/>
    <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
    <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
    <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." 
      verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
     preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
    <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="None" />
```

`

However if i just keep the below setting in web.config it fails to load correctly

```
       `<handlers>
        <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
        <add name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" path="*" verb="OPTIONS" 
        modules="ProtocolSupportModule" resourceType="Unspecified" 
        requireAccess="None" />
        </handlers> `
```

Is there any setting that the above configuration prevents the javascripts from loading correctly on the page?

Comment: I assume they "don't work" because the server returns an error when it tries to load the script file. Can you look in the developer tools and add in what the error is, if any

Comment: it gives the error that $ sign in missing for jquery and a function that is being used is missing , but this causes the entire page to give blank in the browser